# Crystal Reports 2013: Formula field will not display on page

Tags: crystal-reports, crystal-reports-2013

I have a formula called PickOutstanding. Here is the code:

```
if OnLastRecord and {@Calc} < 0 THEN 
    toText({@shipctns}-{#RTotal0}) & " Outstanding"
```

which works on the report but does not show. For example:
In the first image is my report, with where `@PickOutstanding` is highlighted

[image: Report]

`@PickOutstanding` does not show. However when I click into it:

[image: InsideReport]

It clearly is showing right there. What could be causing it to be hidden on the report itself and how do I get it to show?

> Full images in case it is difficult to see the difference between pictures

Pic1:

[image: FullPicture1]

And Pic2:

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was an oversight on my part. `OnLastRecord` was only working on the very last record in the report. Did not work multi group. Will look into getting it to work per group.